# terraform looking using for_each and handling multiple security rules

Tags: oracle, terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating multiple security lists, and each security lists has different ingress and egress rules, Could you please help me how we can manage in the below resource creation.

I am thinking to add a condition like contains[each.value.sec_list_name], "test"], it should only add rules only to that security list.

I am not sure how to manage this stuff...

```
resource "oci_core_security_list" "these" {
  for_each = {
    for sec_list in local.security_lists : "${sec_list.subnet_name}.${sec_list.sec_list_name}" => sec_list
  }
  vcn_id         = oci_core_vcn.these[each.value.vcn_name].id
  compartment_id = each.value.compartment_id
  display_name   = "${each.value.subnet_name}-${each.value.sec_list_name}"
  defined_tags   = each.value.defined_tags
  freeform_tags  = each.value.freeform_tags

   #  egress, proto: TCP  - no src port, no dst port
  dynamic "egress_security_rules" {
    iterator = rule
    for_each = [for x in each.value.egress_rules != null ? each.value.egress_rules : local.default_security_list_opt.egress_rules :
      {
        proto : x.protocol
        dst : x.dst
        dst_type : x.dst_type
        stateless : x.stateless
        description : x.description
    } if x.is_create && x.protocol == "6" && x.src_port_min == null && x.src_port_max == null && x.dst_port_min == null && x.dst_port_max == null]

    content {
      protocol         = rule.value.proto
      destination      = rule.value.dst
      destination_type = rule.value.dst_type
      stateless        = rule.value.stateless
      description      = rule.value.description
    }
  }
}

Any help is highly appreciated
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: The problem is it is creating the ingress and egress rules in all the security lists across subnets available in a Virtual network... we need to handle it by creating this rules in a particular security list.

Comment: You have to provide all values of your variables and locals. Also any errors you get.